# Is there a way to test localization other than changing the thread's CurrentCulture?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, localization, globalization

In an ASP .Net MVC application. I want to make sure my code is getting its strings from the resource files of the correct culture. I know I can put something like the following on the code:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = myCultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = myCultureInfo;
```

and it will work. I was just wondering if there is a way of doing it without modifying the source code. I remember someone showed me quite a while ago that by changing some setting in IE could do the trick but I do not what exactly he changed and if you can do something similar with Chrome and/or FireFox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the  element in your web.config to set the culture to some specific value or set it to `auto` meaning that the client settings will be used:

```
<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
```

Now ASP.NET will use the culture configured on the client browser. For example in FireFox:

[image]

I would also recommend you reading the [following blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx) on globalization in ASP.NET.